# Jquery selector doesn't working with ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following data is coming from an ajax response and then I've appended it to the DOM.

```
<label class="switch">  
<input name="new"  
    value=1 type="checkbox"  
    id="switchButton"  
    data-id="'+order.id+'"  
    data-toggle="toggle">  
<span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>
```

I used the follwoing method to sellect the checkbox value and toggle the state of the setButton div but it is not working. the jquery code is placed inside document ready function.

```
$('#switchButton').click(function(){
                $('#setButton').toggle();
            });
```

The div which i want to hide and show is as follow:

```
<div class="setButton" style="display: none;" id="setButton">
            <button type="button" name="button"></button>
</div>
```

**Note: When I do the functionality in JavaScript it works but it misses some clicks, say once it is clicked the button will be displayed but when click again it doesn't hide it and when clicked again it will hide it.**

Comment: Did you tried `$("#switchButton").live("click", function(){`?

Possibly this is the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/how-do-i-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements-with-jquery

Comment: yes it says live is not a function. I think it is deprecated alternative to live is on(). but on also doesn't work.

Comment: Try this `$('body').on('click', '#switchButton', function() { $('#setButton').hide(); });`. Took reference from link added in @MackMon's comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use **hide** method for e.g

```
$('#switchButton').click(function(){
            $('#setButton').hide();
        });
```

Comment: i want to show it again when the button is off.

Comment: use .show() for e.g. $('#switchButton').click(function(){
            $('#setButton').show();
        });

Comment: i want to hide and show it based on the value of the checkbox. when you click check box it will be shown but when you click it agian it will be hide.

Comment: Try Like This  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#check").change(function(){
    if(this.checked){
     $("#d").hide();
    }else{
    $("#d").show();
    }
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

Check Me To Hide Below Div:-<input type="checkbox" id="check"/>
<div id="d">Content</div>
</body>
</html>